# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator_lib' has no attribute 'LinearRegressor'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, attributeerror

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[1])]
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)
```

My code is above.
Then it shows the error

> "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator_lib' has no attribute 'LinearRegressor'"

Python 3.5.2

Comment: Facing the same problem here. Python - 2.7.12 and Tensorflow version is 1.4.1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Might be you are using older tensorflow version, as [`tf.estimator.LinearRegressor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor) included with `tensorflow=1.3.0`.

upgrade your tensorflow installation

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==1.3.0
```

Comment: I tried "pip install --upgrade tensorflow" beforehand but it kept updating only to 1.2.1.

Adding the version like you said did the trick.